# How to maintain one page values(search values and table record values) after redirected to another page

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, ajax, spring

In my page, I have a hyperlink to go to next page, after clicking back button, i cant see the values in the before page. I don't know how maintain session for all the search values and table values.I m using AJAX, JSP, Javascript and Spring concept for my project.

Is there any functionality to maintain session or before page value in JQuery,AJAX,JavaScript?

Answer (score 1):

This is possible with localStorage:

When you need to set a variable that should be reflected in the next page(s), use:

```
var someVarName = "value";
localStorage.setItem("someVarName", someVarName);
```

get it like in next page

```
var someVarName = localStorage.getItem("someVarName");
```